# route53 cost with geolocation routing policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am planning to have geolocation based policy for domain and few subdomains.
Right now domain and subdomains point to single EC2 instance. If I add another instance with geolocation routing policy, Do I need to pay $50 for each policy?

Comment: Where did you read that a policy is $50?

Comment: I see now, your're talking about Traffic flow policies, not Geo DNS Queries

Comment: Ah so Geo DNS policy will not incur additional charges besides regular DNS lookup charges?